# Xamarin.forms shared project giving error while creation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I create a new xamarin.forms project it is giving error.

"Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\XAMARIN\XAMARIN\3.9.236.0\Packages'":

Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296: Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.1.6296'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author"

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

I have contact Xamarin Support as well but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your nuget package manager. that will resolve the issue.

Source: https://askgif.com/blog/146/why-xamarin-forms-shared-project-giving-error-while-creation/

open your visual studio
go to tools -> Extensions & Updates -> select updates -> select visual studio gallery then update your nuget package manager.

This will resolve your issue.
I had the same problem, after researching a lot i found this solution.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: select as answer if this helped you. :) glad to help you.

Comment: Hi, NuGet Package Manager is not found under the update tab. Any suggestion?